# What else can I do with my superzoom point-and-shoot that would be tricky with a shorter focal length?

Tags: superzoom

I have a Canon PowerShot SX60 with a massive 65x zoom range (21-1365 mm equivalent). There have been some compromises (small sensor, small aperture), but the main selling point is probably that zoom anyway. I bought it mainly to take pictures of birds and other animals (that are quite a long way away), which it does very well. But I was wondering now, what else is a very long focal length useful for? What can I do with it that would be tricky/impossible with a shorter focal length? As an example of what I'm looking for, this answer explains how to get a shallow depth-of-field by zooming in, which would otherwise be tricky with a point-and-shoot:

[What are the depth-of-field capabilities of point & shoot cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/10001/61896)

Comment: This is too broad to be answered here. Most *what*? What do you want to do?

Comment: This is the wrong way around - you got something you didn't need and now you are looking for problems that it can solve. Start from a problem, and get something that solves it.

Comment: @Aganju I originally got it to take pictures of birds and other animals, which it does wonderfully. I'm just wondering if there's anything else that the zoom range could be useful for (e.g. getting a shallow depth-of-field that would otherwise be tricky with a point-and-shoot).

Comment: @mattdm I could rephrase it somewhat: what is a very long focal length useful for? What can I do with it that would be tricky/impossible with shorter focal lengths?

Comment: @mdriesen Sounds better to me.

Comment: @mattdm I edited the question a bit. Should I edit the title too?

Comment: @mdriesen Yes please.

Comment: @mattdm I changed the title. Not sure that will fix the broadness of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just one of the many options: try the [Brenizer method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brenizer_Method) to create pictures with a shallow depth of field using stitching and a long focal length.

Answer (score 0):

You could try shooting sports, which is another situation where you are usually further away frm your subject than would be ideal. However, especially if you try to shoot indoors, you will probably quickly find that the poor low-light performance induced by the small sensor and narrow aperture will become limiting.